# b[i]=new Button(months[i]); can I pass a variable to the Button constructor in java like this,

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to set the label of Buttons in java,and I've declared an array of `Button` class as `Button b[12]` and a String array declared as `String months[12]`.

The String array consists of 12 strings with the names of months, and I'm trying to set label of every button by code below:

`b[i] = new Button(months[i]);`

Although, I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` Exception here...

What's the solution?

Comment: Post your actual code here

Comment: I'm sure you write the code like this `for(int i = 0; i <= months.length; i++)` right?

Comment: `Button` assumes AWT. Why use AWT and not Swing?

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception indicates that you are attempting to access memory further than you previously declared. I'm pretty sure your code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 1 /* or 0 maybe? doesn't matter... */; i <= 12; i++) {
    b[i] = new Button(months[i]);
}
```

Actually, it cannot work, since you are trying to access memory at 13th. We index elements from 0, so months[12] is really 13th element, which you haven't allocated memory for.

Correct code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    b[i] = new Button(months[i]);
}
```

It "will" just work as long as `months` array is the same length or longer than `b` array.

Anyway: please post your full code, I'll edit my answer a little bit then.

Comment: m4tx, the clairvoyant :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I guess I'll join you in spirit. +1